# (Source Insight) How to hide references of function definition in Relation Window?

Tags: function, window, relation, source-insight

I am using "Relation Window" view in Source Insight and want to know how to hide references of function when it's just a function definition(usually in header files) as it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Relation pane and then "Relation Window Properties"

[image]

Select Referenced by Functions

[image]